# Laplace inverse transform of a complex function

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a complex expression and I need to find the laplace inverse transform of this complex term.

The expression is

$$\Large{ e^{\Large{-\frac{x\sqrt{A^2+4Bs}}{2B}}}}$$

In the above expression $A$, $B$, and $x$ can be considered constant.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, you want that expression divided by $s$, if you're trying to do what I think you;re trying to do.

Comment: @ Ron : Thank you so much for your comment. Yes, you are correct. But I thought the laplace inverse transform of 1/s and the expression I wrote could be separated according to the covolution theorem. That is why I only included the exponential term there. Can we do that ?

Comment: I suppose you could, but why create more work for yourself?